# Unexpected behavior in simple jquery selector script

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT: If anyone, ever need this script for some reason, i made a cleaner fully working version: https://jsfiddle.net/qmgob1d5/3/

I have a jquery script that is supposed to highlight elements in a from-to manner. It should work backwards as well.
Here is working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qmgob1d5/

It works fine, until I select zero (first box) as second element. Then the `var Start = Math.min(ClickOne, ClickTwo || 16);` doesn't seems to work as expected. What went wrong?

Here is the script:

```
var FirstClick;
var ClickOne;
var ClickTwo;
$('.ColorPreview').on('click',function() {

var ColorId = $(this).attr('id');
    ColorId = Number(ColorId.split('_')[1]);

    if (!FirstClick) {
        //reset function
        for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        $('#Color_' + i).removeClass('SelectColor'); }
        var ClickTwo;

        ClickOne = ColorId; 
        FirstClick = true; 
        }

    else {
        ClickTwo = ColorId;
        FirstClick = false; }   

console.log('ClickOne ' + ClickOne)
console.log('Clicktwo ' + ClickTwo)

var Start = Math.min(ClickOne, ClickTwo || 16);
var End = Math.max(ClickOne, ClickTwo || 0);

console.log('start ' + Start)
console.log('end ' + End)

    for (var i = Start; i <= End; i++) {
    $('#Color_' + i).addClass('SelectColor'); }

});
```

Comment: What is it that you expect `ClickTwo || 16` to do?

Comment: "doesn't seems to work as expected". What is the expected behavior and what is the behavior you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `ClickTwo` is `0`, the expression `ClickTwo || 16` will evaluate to `16`.

Try

```
var Start = Math.min(ClickOne, ClickTwo == null ? 16 : ClickTwo);
```

Or else initialize `ClickTwo` to `16` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Thank you! for some reason, i thought ClickTwo || 16  will only going to evaluate  to 16 if ClickTwo is null.

Comment: @user2999177 it'll be `16` when `ClickTwo` is `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, or `false`.